# Installing dpkg error "requested operation requires superuser privilege"

Tags: installation, dpkg, usb-modem

Running Ubuntu Version 13.04 and login as administrator and says I need to a superuser to run dpkg, I thought admin was a superuser.  What am I doing wrong?

```
avid@david-Dell-DM051:~/Documents$ dpkg -i vzaccess-7.5_2766f-1ubuntu1110.deb
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
david@david-Dell-DM051:~/Documents$
```

Answer (score 5):

You still need to use sudo to elevate the dpkg installation, do:

```
sudo dpkg -i vzaccess-7.5_2766f-1ubuntu1110.deb
```

then enter your user password.