# Can't install or uninstall anything in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

so I'm trying to install a program doesn't matter which one and then I get this error:

`Processing was halted because there were too many errors.`

then i searched online to find a solution so i tried the following command:

`dpkg --configure -a`

and that gave me the following error:

`pkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege`

so I google again and run the following command:

`sudo dpkg -i vzaccess-7.5_2766f-1ubuntu1110.deb`

which gave me:

`dpkg: error: cannot access archive vzaccess-7.5_2766f-1ubuntu1110.deb': No such file or directory`

and that's where I got stuck
i'm new to linux in general and only recently installed it.

**edit:**

tried running sudo dpkg --configure -a and that gave me this error again. `Processing was halted because there were too many errors.`

and the output of `sude apt update` gave me this

```
~$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu focal Release  
  404  Not Found []
Hit:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]    
Hit:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                            
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
and for sudo apt upgrade. Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
```

I was trying to install f.lux since the build in night light stopped working `

Comment: It clearly says it can not find the file that you trying to run. Where on your system is this file?

Comment: It clearly says I'm new to linux. I don't know what vzaccess-7.5_2766f-1ubuntu1110.deb is but apperently that's what i needed to install to fix the install and uninstall problems

Comment: Why would you try and run a command that you do not know what it does? What did you expect this program to do?

Comment: because of these 2 posts in order:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59492452/cant-install-or-uninstall-anything-in-ubuntu-processing-was-halted-because-th

https://askubuntu.com/questions/321992/installing-dpkg-error-requested-operation-requires-superuser-privilege

Comment: Doing `dpkg --configure -a` would be a sensible thing to do at this point, but that requires superuser privilege, so you should run that as `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.  This will give us information about the state of your package management.  Use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) instead of quotes, so it is formatted correctly and we can parse the information. (Three backticks on the line before and there backticks on the line after the copy/pasted output). It's OK if you don't get the editing right, just copy/paste and we can correct the formatting via moderation tools.

Comment: Can you tell us what software you are trying to install?  Since you are new to Linux, try to stick with software that's in Ubuntu's repositories.  Installing packages from PPA or from `.deb` files that you download off the internet can sometimes break your system, especially if the software is not well-maintained.  Installing software without using apt or dpkg can also be complicated.  If you do have to use software outside of Ubuntu repos and you have to follow some guide, research about each command so that you do not blindly run commands in terminal. This will also help you learn the OS.

Comment: tried running sudo dpkg --configure -a and that gave me this error again. Processing was halted because there were too many errors. I edited with the questions answered

Comment: Why did you add the "nathan-renniewaldock/flux" ppa to your system? Where did you read about doing that? Please edit your question and clearly explain what you are trying to do in the first place, when you started encountering these issues.  The obvious problem you are having is that the ppa does not support `focal`.

Comment: I tried installing f.lux from their official website

Comment: So is your actual, original problem that `redshift` isn't working?

Comment: the original problem problem is the build in night light isn't working. redshift is a different program that i tried installing as well

Comment: haven't figured it out yet. if anyone has an idea that would be nice